# A vector that goes into the plane of the screen ( symbols )

Tags: tikz-arrows

Is there a beautiful symbol that shows  a vector that goes out of the plane of the screen? I would like to show an angle that rotates around the z-axis from top view. I'm aware of the below picture but I've seen another clear and elegant symbol for the head.

[image]

What I'm looking for is a symbol which is similar to mercedes logo like the below picture

[image]

Comment: What exactly don't you know how to draw? A circle? Straight lines (and fill the interior)? You have been around for some time and you know that more straight questions are preferred, rather than “do this for me”. Could you add a minimal example of what you have tried? What's exactly what you don't know?

Comment: @Manuel, I'm not asking you to do the work. I'm asking if there is a supported symbol for in/out vectors in TikZ such a symbol that is used in Geometry. I believe there is no need for minimal working example since the question is whether is there a supported symbol for in/out vector or not. Please don't jump to the conclusion. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the mercedes logo (no car unfortunately) `;-)`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[fill=olive,minimum size=2cm,star, star points = 3,star point height=0.8cm] {};
    \draw[thick,olive] (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the picture. I provided mercedes logo as an example but I think more work need to be done to make it look likes the head of an arrow. I thought TikZ supports the in/out vectors. I could manage to play around with it but I thought there is something more sharp and curved for the head. Thank you so much.

Comment: @CroCo Difficult to guess without an almost approximate picture.

Comment: The problem is that I've seen this symbol before but I couldn't find it. Thank you for your effort. I will try again searching but for the time being I will accept it and use the cross product symbol since it is the standard.